# How to return two parameters in web method?

Tags: java, return-value

How to return the two parameters in web method.?

I have tried these things,but the below code is returning only one parameter.

**web method**

```
public class GetTMSMargin 
{
public String GetTMSMargin(String fd,String td)
{
    return fd;
}  
  }
```

Can any one please mend this code and make me clear?

Thanks in advance!..

Comment: What is a "web method"? Is it actually an android question?

Comment: I am assuming he has a web service that returns 2 values and would like to know how to return both. In that case i sugest returning a JSON string.

Comment: @mario `JSON string` with more than one value is technically still an `array` or `object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send array like this

```
public class GetTMSMargin 
{
    public String[] GetTMSMargin(String fd,String td)
    {
       //your code
       String array[] = {fd, td};
       return array;
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return an array, set, map... and many other things that may contain any number of results (I prefer "result" to "parameter" as an indication of return variable).
BTW: If you are thinking about webservice here than you will need to serialise (JSON or something similar) your array/set/map...

Answer (score 0):

Practically in any computer language you can not return more than one parameter from a function/method.

You might achieve it by returning an Array from function/method. In array you can store more than one value, so in return value you will get more than one value.

```
public String[] getMyValues ( String fd,String td )
{
      String [] returnValues = new String { fd, td };

     return returnValues;
}
```

As being android code you may also use another Class called `ArrayList` for returning multiple values.

however this is just a trick/logic to return more than one value, not a perfect solution.

Comment: oh okay....I need to consume one web service. this is that web service http://54.251.60.177/TMSWebService/MarginService.asmx .This web service is having input values namely fd and td. so i though this web service is having two parameters,if am i wrong please make me clear

Comment: I am trying to consume this web service by soap method.But i cannot consume that web service, thats why i guess may be problem on web method, can you tell how to write the web method for this web service

Comment: I saw your webservice, and let me make clear that both your parameters are of DateTime type, not a String parameter.

Comment: try inserting date in the parameter and check the result :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15965/discussion-between-manick-and-lucifer)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return two values, I suggest you an ArrayList, or a table like Lucifer did.

```
 public ArrayList <String> GetTMSMargin(String fd,String td)
    {
        ArrayList <String> theArray = new ArrayList <String>();
        theArray.add(fd);
        theArray.add(td);
        return theArray;
    }
```

Comment: http://54.251.60.177/TMSWebService/MarginService.asmx this is the web service i am trying to consume by the method SOAP.But its not showing anything.Can you please help me....make me clear about my doubts.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to read up a little more on Java. In Java a function can only return **one** value. If you need to return multiple values, then you will need to return either an `Array` of values (if they are all of the same type, a `List` etc count as an array for these purposes) or an `Object` with these values as its properties, e.g.:

```
class ReturnMultipleValues {

    /**
     * Returns an object containing the two Strings passed.
     */
    public ComplexReturnValue getComplexReturnValue(String arg1, String arg2) {
        ComplexReturnValue value = new ComplexReturnValue(arg1, arg2);
        return value;
    }

    /**
     * Value type which contains 2 strings
     */
    public static class ComplexReturnValue {
        private String arg1;
        private String arg2;

        public ComplexReturnValue(String arg1, String arg2) {
            this.arg1 = arg1;
            this.arg2 = arg2;
        }

        public String getArg1() {
            return arg1;
        }
        public String getArg2() {
            return arg2;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Main method just runs a quick example
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ReturnMultipleValues rmv = new ReturnMultipleValues();
        ComplexReturnValue crv = rmv.getComplexReturnValue("Hello", "World");

        crv.getArg1(); // Returns "Hello"
        crv.getArg2(); // Returns "World"
    }

}
```